# How to split datagrid into same rectangles

Tags: c#, datagrid, colors, cells

I have code that iterates trough all cells how can I make each 4x4 cell to be in different color?

Here is my code:

```
int c = ran.Next(1, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < box_width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < box_height; j++)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                MyClass.grid.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case 2:
                MyClass.grid.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
            case 3:
                MyClass.grid.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                break;
            case 4:
                MyClass.grid.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

This code fills all grid with color that is randomly picked. I want it to split it into some X x X dimension with different color.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int c = ran.Next(1, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < box_width; i += 2)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < box_height; j += 2)
    {
        Color cellColor;

        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                cellColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case 2:
                cellColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
            case 3:
                cellColor = Color.LightBlue;
                break;
            case 4:
                cellColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
        }

        MyClass.grid.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = cellColor;
        MyClass.grid.Rows[j].Cells[i+1].Style.BackColor = cellColor;
        MyClass.grid.Rows[j+1].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = cellColor;
        MyClass.grid.Rows[j+1].Cells[i+1].Style.BackColor = cellColor;
    }
}
```

This assumes that box_width and box_height are the same as the number of rows and cells in your DataGridView.

Let me know if that works for you, I haven't tested it but it seemed right in my head.

However, this will throw an exception if the cells are not in an even 4x4 multiple.  Are you sure they will always be multiples of 4x4?  If not you have to add error checking.

Comment: This works great. How to make it to fit on all screens? For example if my screen resolution will give me different number of cells and at the last column I only have one left and not two? can I paint only that one too?